# patsplit vs split in gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

In the gawk manual, I found two functions `patsplit` and `split`.

- I am wondering what their differences are?
- I understand the purpose of `split`, but what is the purpose of `patsplit`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` matches the default field split, using `FS` (or a specific regular expression if specified): it uses a regular expression to match *field separators*. If you specify `FS=,`, then fields will be split by separating commas — the commas themselves won’t end up in the field contents, they’ll end up in the separators array (if specified).

`patsplit` matches the field pattern split, which can be used instead of the default field split by giving a value for `FPAT`: it uses a regular expression to match *field contents*. For example, if you’re only interested in the numbers given in any record, you could specify `FPAT="[[:digit:].]+"` or use `patsplit` with that regular expression to match all contiguous sets of digits, and manipulate those as fields.

Comment: Thanks. What does `pat` in `patsplit` stand for?

Comment: “pattern”, as in “pattern split”.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is misnamed, because `split` also uses patterns although for separators. What does "FPAT" stand for? "field pattern"?

Comment: Yes, `FPAT` stands for “field pattern”.

Comment: Does `patsplit(string, array, pattern, seps)` do the same as `split(string, array, pattern, seps)`, except that the results in `array` and in `seps` are switched? If yes, aren't the two functions redundant?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379375/674

Comment: @Tim - no, not really, though at first glance they might seem redundant. `FPAT` & `patsplit` were added to `gnu awk` [so as to be able to define fields by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content).

Comment: @don_crissti my question is when both `patsplit` and `split` take the same pattern.

Answer (score 8):

In `split`, you supply a separator; whereas in `patsplit` you match a pattern *between* separators:

```
$ echo 'foo,bar' | awk '{n = split($0,a,/,/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}'
foo
bar
```

whereas

```
$ echo 'foo,bar' | awk '{n = patsplit($0,a,/[^,]*/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}'
foo
bar
```

Comment: I happened on your answer and appreciated the usage of each but found it unclear for split and cross referenced it with the documentation.

It would be more helpful if you used more clear name for the parameters. This is also kinda old so here is what helped me.

split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])

as example: 
split("cul-de-sac", a, "-", seps)

your example: 

string = $0

array = a

fieldsep = /

seps = / <-- this was the confusing part for me?

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html explains both.